# Can't adjust layouts on multiple devices in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to adjust layout without Storyboard in Swift. But using the code below, I can't adjust layout on iPhone Plus series (6+, 7+, and 8+).

**Case1**
Using images based on 640x1136 size, it works on iPhone8, 8+, and X.

```
class Constants {

    // the image parts are based on 640x1136
    static let guiPartsWidthOnDesign = CGFloat(640)
    static var guiPartsMultiplier: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / guiPartsWidthOnDesign

}
```

Make buttons

```
for i in 1..<5 {

    let subButton = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(
        x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2-50*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier,
        y: (100*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier)+CGFloat(i*100),
        width: 187*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier,
        height: 100*Constants.guiPartsMultiplier))
    background.addSubview(subButton)
    subButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    subButton.alpha = 1.0

}
```

The results on multiple devices look the same layout.

**Case2**
Using images based on 750x1334 size, it didn't work well on iPhone8+.

```
class Constants {

    // the images are based on 750x1334
    static let guiPartsWidthOnDesign = CGFloat(750)
    static var guiPartsMultiplier: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / guiPartsWidthOnDesign

}
```

Make buttons (same to the previous code.)

**Result**
[image: iPhone8 Plus]
[image: iPhone8]

As you see, the blue square's y positions are different between iPhone8 and 8 Plus.
(The results of iPhone8 and X are the same.)

How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE**
I tried to use UIStackView, but it didn't work well.
[image: with stackview]

**UPDATE2**

```
//Define this as class variable
    fileprivate lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.axis = .vertical
        sv.alignment = .fill
        sv.distribution = .fillEqually
        sv.spacing = 10
        return sv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        let background = UIImageView.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        background.image = UIImage(named:"BG")
        stackView.addSubview(background)
        //        background.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        background.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

for i in 1..<5 {

    let subButton = UIImageView()
    subButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    subButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    subButton.alpha = 1.0
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(subButton)
    subButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true

}

}
```

*I'm sorry, I don't know but I couldn't upload the screenshot.

**UPDATE3**
I used the following code and the result was like this on all type devices:

[image: result image]

```
//Define this as class variable
    fileprivate lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.axis = .vertical
        sv.alignment = .fill
        sv.distribution = .fillEqually
        sv.spacing = 10
        return sv
    }()

    fileprivate lazy var catBg: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "BG")
        return iv
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(catBg)
        catBg.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        catBg.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        catBg.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.7).isActive = true
        catBg.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: catBg.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.78).isActive = true

        self.catBg.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: catBg.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: catBg.centerYAnchor).isActive = true


        for i in 1..<5 {

            let subButton = UIImageView()
            subButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            subButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            subButton.alpha = 1.0
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(subButton)
            subButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: catBg.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true
            //If you have an image you can remove or change this anchor
            subButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 54).isActive = true
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE4**

My ideal is the center of this image. But so far the result is like the right image.

[image: ideal image]

Comment: because you are using UIScreen.main.bounds.width, which changes with the type of device you use, to be divided by a constant. Of course you will get a different result for a different device?

Comment: @progammingBeignner yeah, you are right. But if I used images based on  640x1136 images and did case1 code. But when I tried case 2, changed only the base image size and the number of image size, it did work well. So I want to ask you why it didn't work if on 750x1334...

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are not using storyboards, I would suggest you using `UIStackview`. In the stackview you specific axis to be vertical and a spacing if you'd like. Set the stackview to fill equally.

Don't using actual frames to calculate position for multiple screen layouts, it will get tedious. 
You should use autolayout constraints in particular anchors.

```
//Define this as class variable
fileprivate lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let sv = UIStackView()
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.axis = .vertical
    sv.alignment = .fill
    sv.distribution = .fillEqually
    sv.spacing = 10
    return sv
}()

fileprivate lazy var catBg: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.image = UIImage(named: "your_img_name")
    return iv
}()

//Put this in viewDidLoad
//Edit

self.view.addSubview(catBg)
//catBg.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
//catBg.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
//catBg.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.7).isActive = true
//catBg.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: catBg.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.78).isActive = true

catBg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
catBg.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
catBg.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
catBg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

self.catBg.addSubview(stackView)
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: catBg.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: catBg.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

for i in 1..<5 {

    let subButton = UIImageView()
    subButton.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    subButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    subButton.alpha = 1.0
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(subButton)
    subButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: catBg.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true
    //If you have an image you can remove or change this anchor
    subButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 54).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: I tried to use stackView, but it didn't work well (I added the result screen in my question). Then do I have only one solution to use auto layout anchors? Can't I adjust layout by using position calculation?

Comment: With the stackView your spacing is already more consistent. Is the rounded pink box a UIView?

Comment: The rounded pink box is included in background view. The blue boxes are UIView, other objects are not.

Comment: What constraints did you add to the stackView?

Comment: Nothing, just wrote the code you mentioned on your answer.

Comment: Do you want the blue buttons to be centered? Could you update your code in the question so that we can see what you have currently got?

Comment: No I don't, just put them on the screen. I updated my question so please check it up. (I'm sorry I couldn't upload the screenshot I don't know though. The result was the background image position was strange and the blue boxes didn't appear.)

Comment: Made changes to the answer you need to added the background first then add the stackView as a subview to the cat image

Comment: I tried it, the all objects are made small thought...I updated my question.

Comment: The objects are smaller because the width of the catBg is 0.7 of your screen, adjust that upwards, max is 1 (one being the width of the screen), also you can adjust the width of the subButton (currently it is 0.3 of the catBg width). I set them as multiples so that they will render the same at all screen sizes. If you don't want the blue buttons to be centered on the catBG, adjust the stackView constraints (don't use centerX, centerY)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It did work well! But if I launched on iPhoneX, the background image didn't fill the screen even I used "catBg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill". White spaces appeared on the top and bottom.

Comment: If the answer is correct please mark it? Regarding your catBG, you could add clipsToBounds = true, but I wouldn't be able to assist further without knowing your image. You could use the image debugger to check that all bounds are as they should be

Comment: Sorry for not showing my image. I updated my question. I tried to add clipsToBounds = true, but the result hasn't changed.